# A problem occurred evaluating project react-native-reanimated

Tags: reactjs

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\84346\Desktop\banh_mi\GoFood\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 21
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Comment: lol, I was not able to run the project for almost one week because of this issue tell me what version of Gradle, node version, react-native you are using?

Comment: i use 7.2 & i fixed my problem by yarn add react-native-reanimated@1.13.4 https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2045

Answer (score 0):

i use 7.2 & i fixed my problem by yarn add react-native-reanimated@1.13.4

[Fix](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2045)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).